# Utilizing AFNetworking with YouTube UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, youtube, afnetworking

I'm hoping someone can help. I am able to list YouTube videos in a `tableView` without `AFNetworking`. The code looks something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLgw1uRYia2CRrFJW7WT4sKoQxvl_pD0c1?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50&key=AIzaSyA8cyh2w-oa5Z5Wzq6em-ir8YCVF8j1zw4&orderby=published"];
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSDictionary *feed = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"feed"]];
 videoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[feed valueForKey:@"entry"]];
[self.videolist reloadData];
```

The images have to load so scrolling is really weird. Therefore, I would like to utilize `AFNetworking`. Here's the code I have tried:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    NSDictionary *feed = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[responseObject valueForKey:@"feed"]];
    videoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[feed valueForKey:@"entry"]];

    NSLog(@"radio==%@",videoArray);

    [self.videolist reloadData];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

And over `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it looks something like this:

```
NSDictionary *video = videoArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [video valueForKeyPath:@"title.$t"];

cell.videotitle.text = title;
```

That doesn't work for some reason, even when there are no errors. Help?

Comment: Log your `*video`. What it contains?

Comment: @orkenstein I'm not sure what that means? :( My NSLog lists all the videos in the YouTube link, is that what you mean?

Comment: It's hard to understand, what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: The videotitle which is textlabel shows up blank when I use the second one with AFHttp. I don't know why.

Comment: As it turns out, this actually works. For some reason it takes a few minutes before all the data is entered. Any idea why?!

Answer (score 0):

The videolist wasn't linked to the table in the Storyboard. The issue is now resolved.